# Add table on DB when another user has a transaction open

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Working at the same project, it happens that some programmers are testing the sw (using transaction), while others want to create or alter tables.

When the second group launch a "CREATE TABLE", the query keeps working until all transaction are closed.

Is there any way to succesfully launch a CREATE query while other user are in transaction?

We are using postgresql for DB and c# with Npgsql for the sw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concurrent CREATE TABLEs should not interfere with each other, unless they are trying to use the same name for the incipient tables.  If they are using different names and still blocking, then you need to describe in more detail what these other transactions are doing.  You can [monitor locks](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) to see exactly what is getting blocked by what.

Answer (score 0):

No, and that is by design. How do you want to drop a table that someone is still using?

The only option is to interrupt these transactions. I can think of two ways to do that:

- Call `pg_cancel_backend` to terminate all transactions that have a lock on the table table.
- Set `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` to some other value than the default "infinite" so that these blocking transactions are canceled by PostgreSQL automatically.

Your developers won't like either of these options, but in this case there is no way to keep everyone happy.

The same holds for `ALTER TABLE`.

Running `CREATE TABLE` as you write shouldn't be a problem, unless you have to drop a table of that name first (see above).

Comment: He is not talking about dropping tables, but creating them

Comment: Oh but he is talking about dropping tables. At least if the developer wants run a create (successfully) on an existing table. Whether it be in use or not.